# When I click the refresh data button, the table appears blank first, and then the new data is rendered. How can I avoid this phenomenon?

Tags: ag-grid, ag-grid-react

Framework: react

Example: https://plnkr.co/edit/ONnLsqILeHCV7fyX

**Current behavior**
Prerequisite: set the column property cellrendererframework.

```
field: colName,
cellRendererFramework: CellRender,
```

When I click the refresh data button, the table appears blank first, and then the new data is rendered.

**Expected behavior**
The table does not appear blank and directly displays the latest data